# Windows 10 host reboots randomly when hyper-v is on

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

I use Windows 10 v1909 (build 18363.836).

I had the need to use the Android simulator in Visual Studio 2019 and it requested that hyper-v be turned on for hardware acceleration. I did it and played a bit with the emulator. So far so good. During the same day, I also wanted to revisit Docker and installed Docker for Windows. Soon after, the PC started to reboot randomly and abruptly. I therefore uninstalled Docker (my VirtualBox VMs were not able to start anyway so I would have uninstalled Docker). The reboots continued. Removed everything Hyper-V in windows features. Still no luck.
At last, I found this [thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=93443#p450407) which made me run bcdedit to turn off hyper-v (how could it be on if it was removed from windows features? Mystery). Since then, no reboots anymore (crossing my fingers as it makes only one day since I applied this solution).

Note that I also tested with Malwarebytes being turned off (this is the only security software I have installed). It still rebooted by itself.

So my question: why am I not able to run Hyper-V and have a stable OS?

Comment: Could be any number of things, drivers not compatible with Hyper-V or poorly written and don't work well virtualized. When you enable Hyper-V, the host OS is moved into the primary partition, some drivers aren't written very well and don't interact with this change.  Failing hardware, like RAM, the extra stress could expose hardware issues.

Comment: @essjae It's kind of depressing. Question: what do you mean by the OS is moved into the primary partition? And what drivers?

Comment: Hyper-V is a type 1 hypervisor, meaning it sits between the hardware and Windows, it doesn't look like it, but it's running in a special VM.  I'd try updating all your drivers straight from the vendor, or at least, via control panel.  I'd also check the event viewer to see if there's any indication of what happened just before the reboot.

Comment: I have  updated the chipset and the LAN drivers with no luck. The event viewer shows nothing at the instant of the reboot (in System) except that there was an unexpected reboot once it restarts. Not sure if I should update the BIOS. It's always frightening to do so and fear that Windows won't behave well after that...